# Compare the sender Id to a given string

Tags: c#, xamarin, events, delegates, sender

I have some buttons like this one but with different IDs:

```
<Button
            android:minWidth="1dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mais"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text= "+"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50sp "/>
```

and the following function:

```
protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if ((sender as Button).Id == "mais") { 
       //do something
   }

   if ((sender as Button).Id == "menos") { 
       //do some other thing
   }
}
```

and I get the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string' ", which I don't understand since **android:id** is defined with a string

I'm assigning the function this way:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mais).Click += Click;
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.menos).Click += Click;
```

Comment: Not that familiar with xamarin but why don't you put a break point on those if conditions to see the true value of your button id. I suspect the @+id in your button declaration is doing something you are not expecting?

Comment: Resource **names** are "transformed" **ids** during compilation for performance reasons. At runtime they are `int` values, if you need to perform a "name" lookup at runtime, you can use `Resources.GetIdentifier`, refer to the linked answer